# C# - Add current date/time to SQL Server table during bulk copy of a csv file

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using the following code to parse a csv file and copy the contents to a SQL Server table:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

namespace CSVTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string csv_file_path = @"pathToCsvFile";
            DataTable csvData = GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(csv_file_path);
            Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);
            InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(csvData);
        }



        private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
        {
            DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
                {
                    csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                    csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                    string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    foreach (string column in colFields)
                    {
                        DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                        datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                        csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                    }
                    while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                    {
                        string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                        //Making empty value as null
                        for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (fieldData[i] == "")
                            {
                                fieldData[i] = null;
                            }
                        }
                        csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return csvData;
        }


        static void InsertDataIntoSQLServerUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable csvFileData)
        {
            using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Database_Name;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
                {
                    s.DestinationTableName = "TableName";
                    s.WriteToServer(csvFileData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The columns of the database table identically match the columns of the csv file which made this easy to write and execute.  But now there's a new requirement: in that same table, I need to write the date/time of the insert of these records into its own column. Assuming I add a column to the database table called `InsertDateTime`, what line(s) of code would I need to add to the above to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in code? If you already have the option to add a column, why not bind a default value GETDATE() to the column. No hassle in code and SQL Server will handle this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned, why do this in code? Just let SQL Server take the hassle out of your hands with a default value... But if you'd really want to do this in code, why not add an extra field after your enumeration?

```
 private static DataTable GetDataTabletFromCSVFile(string csv_file_path)
    {
        DataTable csvData = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
            {
                csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
                csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                string[] colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();
                foreach (string column in colFields)
                {
                    DataColumn datecolumn = new DataColumn(column);
                    datecolumn.AllowDBNull = true;
                    csvData.Columns.Add(datecolumn);
                }

                // ==== HERE ADD COLUMN
                csvData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CreateDateTime"));

                while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }
                    }

                    // === HERE ADD DEFAULT FIELD, but is weird to add to an array, so a but of Linq will help
                    var fieldList = fieldData.ToList(); // will result in List<string>
                    fieldList.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    fieldData = fieldList.ToArray();

                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return csvData;
    }
```

Just that the ReadFields will return an array of fields - and you could create a new array with an extra field etc.. it's just easier to use linq and overwrite your array - it's readable (and anyone can read why this is happening)